# What is the function of air cavity in drums?

Tags: waves, acoustics, resonance, solid-mechanics

I'm trying to understand the function of the air cavity inside drums.
I've read that 'The air cavity inside the drum will have a set of resonance frequencies determined by its shape and size. This will emphasize some frequencies at the expense of others.'
Then what are the resonance frequencies?
Is it the same as a Helmholtz resonator? 
So when the drum membrane is vibrating, it squeezes the air inside the cavity. The air cavity acts like a spring.
But there are different modes of vibration for the drum membrane. Usually when some parts of the membrane are going up other parts are going down, then the air inside the drum is not being squeezed. 
I'm struggling to understand the function of the air cavity in drums and I don't know how to calculate the resonance frequencies. Can someone help? (suppose there is only one membrane stretched over a cylindrical cavity).

Comment: You haven't found an equation for the calculation of the frequencies because this is a coupled system. First you have the air cavity which will act as a column/pipe but the terminating impedances on both sides depend on the membranes. Each membrane will exhibit specific impedance based on the excitation frequency and not only that but the shape of the modes will vary wildly (you can check the modes in any Acoustics textbook about vibration and membranes), resulting in excitation of non-planar (higher order) modes inside the air cavity. I am not an expert in the field but I haven't seen (cont.)

Comment: an analytical solution to such a problem. Maybe you can find some information looking at numerical/computational acoustics on musical instruments. A reference textbook (which I don't know if it has a solution to your problem) is *"Numerical Sound Synthesis: Finite Difference Schemes and Simulation in Musical Acoustics"* by Stefan Bilbao (this link is just to see the book, unfortunately you can't read it there: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16333694-numerical-sound-synthesis).

Comment: Thanks! I've also found an article: Christian, R.S., Davis, R.E., Tubis, A., Anderson, C.A., Mills, R.I., and Rossing, T.D. 
(1984). Effects of air loading on timpani membrane vibrations. J. Acoust. Soc. Am. 
76, 1336-1345.

Comment: That's good. If you manage to find an answer to your original question please take the time to post it here and accept it as the answer (you can answer your own questions and accept them) so that others can benefit from it.